# Does every positive rational number appear once and exactly once in the sequence $\{f^n(0)\}$ , where $f(x):=\frac1{2 \lfloor x \rfloor -x+1} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, elementary-set-theory, recursion

Consider the map $f:\mathbb Q^+ \to \mathbb Q^+$ defined as $f(x):=\dfrac1{2 \lfloor x \rfloor -x+1} , \forall x \in \mathbb Q^+$ ; then is the function

$g:\mathbb Z^+ \to \mathbb Q^+$ defined as $g(n):=f^n(1)=\underbrace{(f \circ f \circ \ldots f}_{n \text{ times}})(1)$ a bijection?  That is, do the iterates of $f()$ hit all positive rationals?

Comment: what happens at x=-1?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry $x=-1$ is not in the domain or range

Comment: That's refering to n. I got it, the sequence starts $f_0(0)=1$, $f_1(0)=f(f(_0)(0))=1/2$, next is 2, 1/3, etc...

Comment: Where did you come across this particular $f$?  What have you tried on the problem so far?

Comment: It is not too difficult to see that $f$ is a bijection $\mathbb Q_{\ge0}\to\mathbb Q_{>0}$, but do you have any particular reason to suspect it has only one orbit?

Comment: The function sends $\dfrac pq$ to $\dfrac q{p+q-2(p\bmod q)}$, and if $p/q$ is in lowest terms, then this result is too. So possibly it might be easier to understand as a weird integer recurrence.

Comment: This is known as Calkin–Wilf sequence

Comment: I tweaked the definition slightly to start from $1$ rather than from $0$, since that lets the domain and range be explicitly defined as positive rather than non-zero, and the shift doesn't really affect anything.

Comment: @gtrrebel Given that that answers the question explicitly, maybe it should be fleshed out with some of the information from the Wikipedia link (and a pointer) and turned into an answer?

Comment: Yep, although I'd like to find a online proof for that

Comment: A related problem (sorry, I don't remember the source for this): the Taylor series of $$\prod_{k=0}^\infty(1+x^{2^{k}} + x^{2^{k+1}}) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$$ has the property that $g(n) =\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.

Comment: @gtrrebel I'll bet that looking at continued fraction expansions would lead towards a proof - this is probably related to iterating over all finite sequences of integers sorted by total sum (i.e., '1', '2', '1 1', '3', '2 1', '1 2',  '1 1 1', '4', etc.) in some suitable Gray code order (with each sum corresponding to one level in the Calkin-Wilf tree).

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, these are the reciprocals of the numbers $q_n$ in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050136/prove-that-this-recurrence-relation-algorithm-generates-all-positive-rational-nu), and I proved that they enumerated $\Bbb Q^+$ without repetition.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Looks so -- at least both Wikipedia and OEIS claim that the halving-based recurrence in the other question defines the same sequence as the step-by-step one in this question. But I don't think it is at all obvious _that_ the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @Henning: It took a bit of work, but I’ve managed to supply the details.

Comment: The title has $f^n(0)$, the body, $f^n(1)$. I guess it makes little difference, since $f(0)=1$, but still....

Comment: @Gerry: The body had $f^n(0)$ too, until Steven Stadnicki edited it. I don't really grasp his point; is $\mathbb Q_+\to \mathbb Q_+\setminus{1}$ much nicer than $\mathbb Q_{\ge 0} \to\mathb Q_+$?

Answer (score 3):

As Henning noted in the comments,

$$\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{p}q\right)&=\frac1{2\left\lfloor\frac{p}q\right\rfloor-\frac{p}q+1}\\
&=\frac{q}{2q\left(\frac{p-(p\bmod q)}q\right)-p+q}\\
&=\frac{q}{p+q-2(p\bmod q)}\;.
\end{align*}$$

If we let $p_0=q_0=1$ and define $p_n$ and $q_n$ by the recurrences

$$\begin{align*}
p_{n+1}&=q_n\\
q_{n+1}&=p_n+q_n-2(p_n\bmod{q_n})\;,
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

clearly $g(n)=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$. Note that we can eliminate $q_n$ and reduce $(1)$ to

$$p_{n+1}=p_{n-1}+p_n-2(p_{n-1}\bmod{p_n})\;,$$

with initial conditions $p_0=p_1=1$.

An easy induction shows that $p_{2n}>p_{2n+1}$ for $n>0$, and $p_{2n+1}<p_{2n+2}$ for $n\ge 0$.

> If $n>0$ is even, then by the induction hypothesis $p_{n-1}<p_n$, so $$p_{n+1}=p_{n-1}+p_n-2p_{n-1}=p_n-p_{n-1}<p_n\;.\tag{2}$$
>
> If $n$ is odd, then $p_{n-1}>p_n$; let $p_{n-1}=kp_n+r$, where $k\ge 1$ and $0\le r<p_n$. Then $$p_{n+1}=p_{n-1}+p_n-2(p_{n-1}\bmod{p_n})=(k+1)p_n-r\ge 2p_n-r>p_n\;.$$

Let $r_0=1$, and define $r_n$ by the recurrence

$$\begin{align*}
r_{2n+1}&=r_n\\
r_{2n+2}&=r_n+r_{n+1}\;.
\end{align*}\tag{3}$$

Clearly $r_0=r_1=p_0=p_1=1$. Suppose that $r_k=p_k$ for $k\le 2n+1$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
p_{2n+2}&=p_{2n}+p_{2n+1}-2(p_{2n}\bmod{p_{2n+1}})\\
&=r_{2n}+r_{2n+1}-2(r_{2n}\bmod{r_{2n+1}})\\&=r_{n-1}+2r_n-2\big((r_{n-1}+r_n\big)\bmod{r_n}\big)\\
&=r_{n-1}+2r_n-2(r_{n-1}\bmod{r_n})\\
&=r_n+\big(p_{n-1}+p_n-2(p_{n-1}\bmod{p_n})\big)\\
&=r_n+p_{n+1}\\
&=r_n+r_{n+1}\\
&=r_{2n+2}\;,
\end{align*}$$

and $r_{2n+3}=r_{n+1}=r_{2n+2}-r_n=r_{2n+2}-r_{2n+1}=p_{2n+2}-p_{2n+1}=p_{2n+3}$ by (2). Thus, $r_n=p_n$ for all $n\ge 0$.

For $n\ge 1$ let $a_n=r_{n-1}=p_{n-1}$. Then $a_1=1$, and it follows from $(3)$ that

$$a_{2n}=r_{2n-1}=r_{n-1}=a_n$$

and

$$a_{2n+1}=r_{2n}=r_{n-1}+r_n=a_n+a_{n+1}$$

and hence that $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is the sequence defined in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050136/prove-that-this-recurrence-relation-algorithm-generates-all-positive-rational-nu). In my [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1050557/12042) to that question I showed that if $q_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, the sequence $\langle q_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a bijection from $\Bbb Z^+$ to $\Bbb Q^+$, and the rational numbers $q_n$ are just the reciprocals of the numbers $g(n)$.

Comment: Good work, +1! Unfortunately, even though this proof demonstrates _that_ it works, I still find myself wondering _how_ it works, intuitively. But one can't have everything ...