# A rational orbit that's provably dense in the reals?

Tags: sequences-and-series, dynamical-systems, rational-numbers, rational-functions, arithmetic-dynamics

Iterating the map $\ \ x\ \mapsto\  x-\frac{1}{x},\ \ $ the orbit of initial point $2$ is ["probably" dense in $\mathbb{R}$](http://www.math.grin.edu/~chamberl/papers/mario_digits.pdf). Is there an explicit rational mapping together with an initial rational whose orbit is *provably* dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

**NB**: "Rational mapping" here means simply a function from rationals to rationals, not the [definition in algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_mapping).

---

EDIT: Does the following approach work? ...

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1180622/16397) to another posted question proves that with 
$$f(x)=\dfrac1{2 \lfloor x \rfloor -x+1}$$the rational orbit $$1,\ f(1),\ f(f(1)),\ ...,\ f^n(1),\ ...$$
is the [Calkin-Wilf sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree) containing every positive rational exactly once, and is therefore dense in $\mathbb{R^+}$.

**Question:** Can it be shown that in this Calkin-Wilf sequence the *even*-index rationals alone are dense in $\mathbb{R^+}$, and likewise for the *odd*-index rationals?

If so, then, noting that $f(0)=1$, we can obtain a rational orbit that's provably dense in the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ by simply taking 
$$0,\ g(0),\ g(g(0)),\ ...,\ g^n(0),\ ...$$
with 
$$g(x) =  
\begin{cases} 
-f(x)  & \text{if }x\ge 0 \\
f(-x) & \text{if }x<0 
\end{cases}$$
so
$$g^n(0) =  
\begin{cases} 
f^n(0)  & \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\
-f^n(0) & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}. 
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Start from the theorem that for any irrational $\mu \in (0,1)$ the set 
$$
\{2^k \mu\} : k \in \Bbb{N}
$$
where (following Knuth's Concrete Mathematics) the notation $\{x\}$ means the fractional part of $x$ ($ \equiv x-\lfloor x \rfloor$) is dense in $(0,1)$.

Now look at the map 
$$
x \mapsto \frac{x - \frac{1}{x}}{2} $$
with some initial point $x_0$.
The equation for this map superficially looks a lot like the example you give.  But that $2$ in the denominator does a couple of things:

- $x_n$ is the $n$-th guess you would obtain if you were naively to try to find $\sqrt{-1}$ using Newton's algorithm with a starting guess of $x_0$.
- We can express the value of $x_n$ in closed form (I attribute this to Carl Bender in a course at MIT in 1973 or so, but of course it may have been known much earlier):

$$ x_n = \cot \left( 2^n \cot^{-1}x_0 \right)$$

But as long as $\cot{-1}x_0$ is not a rational multiple of $2\pi$, by the theorem stated above the set 
$$
\{2^k \cot^{-1}x_0\} : k \in \Bbb{N}
$$
is dense in $(0,2\pi)$.

So the set of values of $x_k$ is the set of cotangents of a dense set on the circle; in turn, the set of values of $x_k$ is dense on the real line.  An example is an initial value of $x_0 = 2$.

Comment: "Start from the theorem..." : that's not a theorem, that's just false (e.g. take  for $\mu$ an irrational number with no $11$ in its binary expansion). You have to be more careful; the binary expansion of $\mu$ must contain all finite strings of digits. The binary Champernowne constant, for instance, does the trick. Otherwise, pretty nice argument.

Comment: @D.Thomine - So for this answer to work, we need to find a *rational* $x_0$ such that the binary expansion of $\cot^{-1}x_0$ *provably* contains every finite binary string. Isn't that beyond current mathematics?

Comment: @r.e.s. : yes, you are right. I didn't catch that. So this method doesn't work, after all.