# Binary expansion of $\frac{1}{\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, decimal-expansion

> Prove that the binary expansion of $\dfrac{1}{\pi}\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{5}{12}\right)$ has strings of $0$s or $1$s of arbitrary length.

I didn't see how we can calculate the binary expansion of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ or $\pi$. Is there some other way of solving this question?

Comment: I do not know if this is really relevant, but since $\arctan(z)=\text{Im}\log(1+iz)$ and $5+12i=(3+2i)^2$, the question is more or less equivalent to showing that $(3+2i)^{2^k}$ is often close to a real number (i.e.has a small imaginary part, compared to the real part).

Comment: where did you find this question ?

Comment: @mercio I was solving a problem and needed to prove this as a step in the solution.

Comment: this could very well be the sort of thing that is "obviously true" (because a number taken randomly in a unit interval will have this property with probability $1$) but completely hopeless to prove.

Comment: I knew this was a hidden duplicate : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1615708/is-x-n1-fracx-n2-frac2x-n-bounded

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Don't all numbers in base 2 contain only 0s and 1s? Also this value in binary is about $0.0010000000101011$ according to wolfram alpha.

Answer (score 0):

NOT A SOLUTION:

Something that may be of use

\begin{equation}
 \arctan\left(\frac{x + y}{1 - xy}\right) = \arctan(x) + \arctan(y)
\end{equation}

Here,

\begin{equation}
\frac{x + y}{1 - xy} = \frac{5}{12}
\end{equation}

Which has the integer solutions $x,y = -5$

and so,

\begin{equation}
 \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\arctan\left(\frac{5}{12}\right)\right] = \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\arctan(-5) + \arctan(-5)\right] = -\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(5) 
\end{equation}

As before, unsure if this will be of help.